# php magento installation error on local server

Tags: php, magento-1.7

While installing the Magento on local server I am getting the error "This webpage has a redirect loop"..

I tried the option that was discussed on some forums but not able to solve the issue...

Please help me to find the solution for this

Comment: Your script keeps getting redirected from page to page. Find that script. Could be in the config base url

Comment: You should check your .htaccess file for redirects

Comment: checked the .htaccess file ..but did not solve the problem.....

Comment: Try to clear your cookies and allow thirdparty cookies. You should also check your windows / linux time

Comment: i have  cleared the cookies and also allow third party cookies....but it not helped...

Comment: the windows/linux time i dont understand what actully to do...??

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I've read in a blog that sometimes web apps have problems with the windows / linux time and it **could** end in a redirection loop.

Comment: i use google chrome, mozila firefox, and IE ...

Comment: now I have tried fresh installation ....though it starts the installation ....the same error is appearing again and again....

Comment: Are you using http://localhost as the url? if so try using http://127.0.0.1